# Lots of nested loops - How can I make it faster?

Tags: matlab, nested-loops, performance

This part of my code, shown below, is taking long time to run due to many nested loops. Is there a way these nested loops can be obviated to make it run faster?

```
for k = 1:numel(UpscaledZLen.pq)
    for j = 1:numel(UpscaledRowLen.pq)
        for i = 1:numel(UpscaledColLen.pq)

            iZ = 1;
            while iZ <= UpscaledZLen.pq(k)
                for ZLag = 1:iZ

                    ihRow = 1;
                    while ihRow <= UpscaledRowLen.pq(j)
                        for hRowLag = 1:ihRow

                            ihCol = 1;
                            while ihCol <= UpscaledColLen.pq(i)
                                for hColLag = 1:ihCol
                                    temp1(hColLag) = trapz(AnalGamma(hRowLag,...
                                        1:hColLag,...
                                        ZLag));
                                end
                                temp2(ihCol) = trapz(temp1);
                                ihCol = ihCol + 1;
                            end

                            temp3(hRowLag) = trapz(temp2);
                        end
                        temp4(ihRow) = trapz(temp3);
                        ihRow = ihRow + 1;
                    end

                    temp5(ZLag) = trapz(temp4);
                end
                temp6(iZ) = trapz(temp5);
                iZ = iZ + 1;
            end

            NormVariance_AnalCorrAvg(i, j, k) = (2/((UpscaledRowLen.pq(j)*...
                UpscaledColLen.pq(i)*UpscaledZLen.pq(k))^2))*trapz(temp6);
        end
    end
end
```

This piece of code is trying to implement the following integral expression:

[image]

**EDIT [(SSCCE)](http://sscce.org/):** For a brief example, I took following variable sizes and then used the above piece of code to see how much time it takes to run for these specific variable sizes:

```
nRow = 4;
nCol = 4;
nZ = 4;

RowLenScale.pq = 1:nRow;
ColLenScale.pq = 1:nCol;
UpscaledRowLen.pq = RowLenScale.pq(rem(RowLenScale.pq(end), RowLenScale.pq) == 0);
UpscaledColLen.pq = RowLenScale.pq(rem(ColLenScale.pq(end), ColLenScale.pq) == 0);

ZLenScale.pq = 1:nZ;
UpscaledZLen.pq = ZLenScale.pq(rem(ZLenScale.pq(end), ZLenScale.pq) == 0);

AnalGamma = rand(nRow, nCol, nZ);
```

For this example it takes only **0.321976 seconds**, whereas, for original case where `nRow = 100;`, `nCol = 100;` and `nZ = 20;` it took more than 24 hours and was still running with outermost loop index at `k = 4`.

Comment: Provide an example we can run, or profile it and tell us where the bottleneck is.

Comment: I was trying to run it but takes long time. After waiting for ~15 min the code was still running and reached only the 2nd index of the outer most (`k`) loop variable. My guess is that the repeated nestedness is causing it to take a lot of time.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html or provide a [SSCCE](http://SSCCE.org)

Comment: @OlegKomarov: Please see the edit. It includes SSCCE.

Comment: It's hard to say what you want to do but you're definitely coding it in the wrong way. You need to explain what you want to achieve because that's too many unnecessary loops. No wonder that it's taking ages but you might actually have billions of iterations.

Comment: @OlegKomarov: I have included an analytical expression for what I am trying to implement in the code. Also, I am using remainder function to find the `UpscaledRowLen`, `UpscaledColLen` etc. because of some upscaling which is not important in this question. Thanks.

Comment: The product of all upper limits of integration is a rough estimate of the number of iterations. Check that it actually totals to something feasible. In general, brute force approaches are always limited by resources, e.g. CPU which translates into time, RAM, and eventually space. Once you cross the feasibility of the problem, you need to rethink your approach. 

All in all I want to say, do you really need 6 integrals? 

Maybe this is related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/159333/understanding-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-gamma-function

Comment: Could you please edit your analytic expression? The one you postet is not valid. What are the integration variables, what variables is `analgamma` dependent from?

Comment: What are you integrating with respect to??

Comment: Are the outer three `for` loops relevant to this question as they don't perform the quadrature? The performance issue is with the inner part I'd guess and it would help simplify the question to isolate this code. It also might even help the JIT optimize the code if this was turned into a subsection. Another suggestion performance-wise: have you tried replacing the `while` loops with `for` loops with `break` statements to see if that might run faster?

Comment: Stupid autocorrect -from above: subsection -> subfunction. Also, it's hard for anyone here to test this and provide truly useful help without access to the unfortunately-named `AnalGamma` function or some proxy.

Comment: I keep checking this post just to giggle on the name of the function.

Comment: I think [Loop optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_optimization) theorically may help you.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to integrate in some direction over discrete values? Have you considered using the sum?

Comment: Is there any reason to use a fixed step size of 1 for all numeric integrations? Increasing this step size to two would reduce the computation time by a factor of about 64.

Comment: In the example, `AnalGamma` is defined using `rand` – are you serious about this, or is it just for the sake of the example? If you are, we're talking stochastic integrals, which is a special topic. If not, what is the actual function you are trying to integrate? Or is `AnalGamma` actually given as a 3d matrix? Then you don't need integration, you need simply a `sum`

Comment: @A.Donda: It's just for the sake of example. `AnalGamma` is a 3D matrix, which is a function of length along row, length along column and length along z-direction, respectively. That's what I am trying to integrate.

Comment: @Pupil, ok but is it given as a function, or directly as a 3D matrix?

Comment: @A. Donda: I computed numerical values for `AnalGamma` from an analytical expression which is a function of length along row, length along column and length along z-direction, respectively. That's the reason I abbreviated the variable name as `Anal__` to indicate it's computed from an analytical expression. However, to answer your question: `AnalGamma` is given directly as a 3D matrix after I compute the numerical values from the analytical expression.

Comment: @Pupil: Do I get that bounty? :-)

Comment: It'll go to you automatically :) . Apparently, I don't get right result with your code. `AnalGamma` should decrease with increasing `hRowLag`/`hColLag` and `ZLag`, but it's increasing.

Comment: @Pupil, no, automatically I only get half of the bounty. :) – You mean that `NormVariance_AnalCorrAvg` should decrease, right? Well, at least with the example using `rand`, all the integrated values are positive, so the integral can only increase with increasing upper limit. And as I wrote, I checked that my code gives the same result as yours, except for that initialization error.

Answer (score 7):

First of all, your code is faulty, because temporary variables are not initialized and values left from the last iteration are still present in the next. After correcting this and replacing `while` by `for` loops, the code looks like this:

```
NormVariance_AnalCorrAvg = nan(numel(UpscaledColLen.pq), numel(UpscaledRowLen.pq), numel(UpscaledZLen.pq));
for k = 1 : numel(UpscaledZLen.pq)
    for j = 1 : numel(UpscaledRowLen.pq)
        for i = 1 : numel(UpscaledColLen.pq)

            temp6 = nan(1, UpscaledZLen.pq(k));
            for iZ = 1 : UpscaledZLen.pq(k)
                temp5 = nan(1, iZ);
                for ZLag = 1 : iZ
                    temp4 = nan(1, UpscaledRowLen.pq(j));
                    for ihRow = 1 : UpscaledRowLen.pq(j)
                        temp3 = nan(1, ihRow);
                        for hRowLag = 1 : ihRow
                            temp2 = nan(1, UpscaledColLen.pq(i));
                            for ihCol = 1 : UpscaledColLen.pq(i)
                                temp1 = nan(1, ihCol);
                                for hColLag = 1:ihCol
                                    temp1(hColLag) = trapz(AnalGamma(hRowLag,...
                                        1:hColLag,...
                                        ZLag));
                                end
                                temp2(ihCol) = trapz(temp1);
                            end
                            temp3(hRowLag) = trapz(temp2);
                        end
                        temp4(ihRow) = trapz(temp3);
                    end
                    temp5(ZLag) = trapz(temp4);
                end
                temp6(iZ) = trapz(temp5);
            end
            NormVariance_AnalCorrAvg(i, j, k) = (2/((UpscaledRowLen.pq(j)*...
                UpscaledColLen.pq(i)*UpscaledZLen.pq(k))^2))*trapz(temp6);

        end
    end
end
```

The initialization here also leads to preallocation of arrays, which is one of the basic recommended things to speed up loops. In this case, however, it doesn't have an effect.

In order to benchmark the code I use your snippet using `rand`, but with

```
nRow = 20;
nCol = 20;
nZ = 2;
```

On my computer, the cleaned-up code needs 25.5 seconds to complete.

---

How to make it faster? Good old vectorization:

The innermost loop over `hColLag` can be replaced by a `cumtrapz`, descreasing the runtime to 8.2 seconds.

```
temp1 = cumtrapz(AnalGamma(hRowLag, 1 : ihCol, ZLag), 2);
```

The same holds for the loop over `ihCol`, decreasing the runtime to 1.85 seconds.

```
temp2 = cumtrapz(cumtrapz(AnalGamma(hRowLag, 1 : UpscaledColLen.pq(i), ZLag), 2), 2);
```

The next outer loop over `hRowLag` just serves to compute several analogous `trapz`s. That's not necessary, since `trapz` is fully vectorized; the loop can be replaced by one call, which decreases the runtime to 0.34 seconds.

```
temp3 = trapz(cumtrapz(cumtrapz(AnalGamma(1 : ihRow, 1 : UpscaledColLen.pq(i), ZLag), 2), 2), 2);
```

The loop over `ihRow` computes a cumulative integral; using `cumtrapz` brings the runtime down to about 0.07 seconds.

```
temp4 = cumtrapz(trapz(cumtrapz(cumtrapz(AnalGamma(1 : UpscaledRowLen.pq(j), 1 : UpscaledColLen.pq(i), ZLag), 2), 2), 2), 1);
```

Applying the same logic to the loops over `iZ` and `ZLag`, we arrive at the following code

```
NormVariance_AnalCorrAvg = nan(numel(UpscaledColLen.pq), numel(UpscaledRowLen.pq), numel(UpscaledZLen.pq));
for k = 1 : numel(UpscaledZLen.pq)
    for j = 1 : numel(UpscaledRowLen.pq)
        for i = 1 : numel(UpscaledColLen.pq)
            temp6 = cumtrapz(trapz(cumtrapz(trapz(cumtrapz(cumtrapz(...
                AnalGamma(1 : UpscaledRowLen.pq(j), 1 : UpscaledColLen.pq(i), 1 : UpscaledZLen.pq(k)), ...
                2), 2), 2), 1), 1), 3);
            NormVariance_AnalCorrAvg(i, j, k) = (2/((UpscaledRowLen.pq(j)*...
                UpscaledColLen.pq(i)*UpscaledZLen.pq(k))^2))*trapz(temp6);

        end
    end
end
```

with a runtime of 0.043 seconds, an improvement by a factor of about 600.

Writing all these nested `trapz`s and `cumtrapz`s is of course very error-prone. I used a checksum applied to the result saved to a file in order to make sure it is not changed by my changes to the code. Still, you should double check in order to be completely sure.

---

It is probably possible to go even further. The first three for loops again do something cumulative-y, so maybe more `cumtrapz` are in order. `trapz` is not very effectively implemented because it has a lot of error-checking code. Since what it does is basically a sum over averaged values (see [trapezoidal rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trapezoidal_rule)), precomputing multidimensional averages on the full grid would allow to translate these calls into calls to `sum`. Simpler than the trapezoidal rule is the [rectangle method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_method), for which you would compute values of your function not at the edges but in the center of the grid cells. And then of course you could try to partially compute the integral analytically; and you can decrease the resolution of your grid.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can do to improve the performance.  First, you can replace the while loops with for loops.  Second, you can replace trapz, an integration, with sum.  If you replace with sum, and instead of computing the sum within each loop you compute sum at the end, you will get some improvment.  Finally you could extract the final multiply calculation.

Is the input to gamma function really (hRowLag, 1:hColLag, ZLag) or is it (hRowLag, hColLag, ZLag).  If the gamma function can be vectorized you could build a mesh to feed the function, rather than looping.

```
temp = zeros(max(UpscaledZLen.pq),max(UpscaledZLen.pq),max(UpscaledRowLen.pq),max(UpscaledRowLen.pq),max(UpscaledColLen.pq),max(UpscaledColLen.pq));
my_integral = zeros(numel(UpscaledZLen.pq), numel(UpscaledRowLen.pq), numel(UpscaledColLen.pq));

for k = 1:numel(UpscaledZLen.pq)
    for j = 1:numel(UpscaledRowLen.pq)
        for i = 1:numel(UpscaledColLen.pq)
            for iZ = 1:UpscaledZLen.pq(k)
                for ZLag = 1:iZ
                    for ihRow = 1:UpscaledRowLen.pq(j)
                        for RLag = 1:ihRow
                            for ihCol = 1:UpscaledColLen.pq(i)
                                for CLag = 1:ihCol
                                    temp(iZ,ZLag,ihRow,RLag,ihCol,CLag,:) = AnalGamma(RLag,1:CLag,ZLag);
                                end
                            end
                        end
                    end
                end
            end
            my_integral(i,j,k) = sum(temp(:));
        end
    end
end

my_z = repmat(permute(UpscaledZLen.pq(:),[3,2,1]),[numel(UpscaledRowLen.pq),numel(UpscaledColLen.pq),1]);
my_r = repmat(permute(UpscaledRowLen.pq(:),[2,1]),[numel(UpscaledRowLen.pq),1,numel(UpscaledZLen.pq)]);
my_c = repmat(UpscaledColLen.pq(:),[1,numel(UpscaledColLen.pq),numel(UpscaledZLen.pq)]);

NormVariance_AnalCorrAvg = my_integral .* 2 ./ (my_z .* my_r .* my_c).^2;
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately, it gives an `out of memory` error.